How to make the duplicate values on columns as 1 row in excel



A
B
C




S.no
Account
Product


1
00125000021lifAAAQ
01t25000008AUatAAG


2
00125000021lifBAAQ
01t25000008AUbIAAW


3
00125000021lifBAAQ
01t25000008AUkJAAW



I have 3 columns. If column B has duplicate values. Then its corresponding values on column C should be placed as new cell in next column.
For eg:  above table Account column B2 and B3 are same. Then I want C3 on D2 cell.



A
B
C
D




S.no
Account
Product



1
00125000021lifAAAQ
01t25000008AUatAAG



2
00125000021lifBAAQ
01t25000008AUbIAAW
01t25000008AUkJAAW



How to do this in excel. Please help. Thanks in advance.
I tried with the formula which is avaliable in google. I am new to excel. I want to show like this in excel



A
B
C
D




S.no
Account
Product



1
00125000021lifAAAQ
01t25000008AUatAAG



2
00125000021lifBAAQ
01t25000008AUbIAAW
01t25000008AUkJAAW




@Excellor I did not found any direct formulae. I sorted the columns then added new column when duplicates found I filled the column and tried. But it is not useful.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"S.no", Int64.Type}, {"Account", type text}, {"Product", type text}}),

//Group by "Account"
//Then create records from each row in the group
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Account"}, {
        {"S.no", each List.First([S.no]), Int64.Type},
        {"Products", (t)=>Record.FromList(t[Product], List.Transform({1..Table.RowCount(t)}, each "Product " & Text.From(_)))},
        {"Count" , each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),

//Expand the grouped table
    #"Expanded Products" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Products",
            List.Transform({1..List.Max(#"Grouped Rows"[Count])}, each "Product " & Text.From(_))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Products",{"Count"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"S.no", "Account"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"




objDic collects all products for each account
objDicCnt gets the quantify of products for each account

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, objDicCnt As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, arrData, arrRes, iR As Long, aTxt
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDicCnt = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 2)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "|" & arrData(i, 3)
            objDicCnt(sKey) = objDicCnt(sKey) + 1
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 3)
            objDicCnt(sKey) = 1
        End If
    Next i
    Dim ColCnt As Long
    For Each sKey In objDicCnt.Keys
        If objDicCnt(sKey) > ColCnt Then ColCnt = objDicCnt(sKey)
    Next
    ReDim arrRes(1 To objDic.Count, 1 To ColCnt + 2)
    Sheets.Add
    oSht.Rows(1).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        aTxt = Split(objDic(sKey), "|")
        iR = iR + 1
        arrRes(iR, 1) = iR
        arrRes(iR, 2) = sKey
        For i = LBound(aTxt) To UBound(aTxt)
            arrRes(iR, i + 3) = aTxt(i)
        Next
    Next
    Range("A2").Resize(iR, ColCnt + 2) = arrRes
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub



Using formulas
If your data set is not that big and you would like a formula you can try this for column D starting from D2.
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)=COUNTIF(B:B,B2),C2,"")

Screenshot results

Just copy and paste the formula as it will become

